# Configuring Sticky Sessions vs Forwarded Headers - Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I'm running a Blazor Server app behind a load balancer. I am aware that [sticky sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-5.0) can be used with ASP.NET Core when SignalR is running behind a load balancer.

I have also read documentation that talks about using [forwarded headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

My question is, if forwarded headers are used, are sticky sessions still required? Or are these two strategies meant to be used together?

Without sticky sessions enabled, I receive the following error:

[image]

This error is resolved when using sticky sessions. I'm wondering if configuring forwarded headers would fix this as well **without the need of sticky sessions**.

Comment: Based on my understanding, the Forwarded headers are used to handle the request with proxy servers and load balancers. And the sticky session limits your application scalability because the load balancer is unable to truly balance the load each time it receives request from a client. With sticky sessions, the load balancer is forced to send all the requests to their original or backup server where the session state was created even though that server might be heavily loaded and there might be another less-loaded server available to take on this request. So, you could use them together.

Comment: @ZhiLv thanks for the info. I've edited my question a bit. Do you know if only adding forwarded headers would solve that error (without sticky sessions). Or are sticky sessions required regardless and forwarded headers are used to provide additional info.

Comment: In my personal experience with Blazor Server, you had to use sticky sessions to prevent the Circuits from breaking (even with a shared connection store like Redis).